# Unable to remove docker-py using ansible pip module

Tags: pip, ansible

Ansible version: 2.9
Python version being used: 3.6+
OS: ubuntu 18
Trying to remove docker-py using pip.
Code snippets I have tried...

```
  post_tasks:
    - pip:
        name: docker-py
        state: absent

   - name: remove docker-py sdk
     pip:
       name: docker-py
       state: absent
```

Document referred: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/docker_container_module.html
package never gets uninstalled.
Direct pip command from shell works

```
pip uninstall docker-py
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: remove docker-py sdk
  become: no
  pip:
    name: docker-py
    state: absent
```

I had `become: yes` for the whole ansible-playbook, i did a override for this task, so may be we should avoid become: yes for pip packages.